# Error installing pretrained models for pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm working on a Windows 10 machine (yes, I know, don't laugh!), and with python 3.7, and I'm trying to install the pretrained models here:

https://github.com/meliketoy/fine-tuning.pytorch

The commands that the website suggests are:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch.git
$ pretrained-models.pytorch
$ python setup.py install
```

Although the website says this is for Python 3.5, and I have 3.7, I think the 3.7 version should be back-compatible, right?

I successfully ran the `git clone`, and the `pretrained-models.pytorch` was actually a `cd` command (which threw me for a loop for a second!). Then I ran into trouble with `python setup.py install`

The error I'm getting is:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build\\bdist.win-amd64\\egg\\pretrainedmodels\\models\\resnext_features\\__pycache__\\resnext101_32x4d_features.cpython-37.pyc.1702181039952'
```

How can I fix this error?

EDIT (in response to a comment): Someone asked for the full traceback. Here it is!

```
(base) G:\>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating pretrainedmodels.egg-info
writing pretrainedmodels.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pretrainedmodels.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to pretrainedmodels.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to pretrainedmodels.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'pretrainedmodels.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'pretrainedmodels.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'pretrainedmodels.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\pretrainedmodels
copying pretrainedmodels\utils.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels
copying pretrainedmodels\version.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels
copying pretrainedmodels\__init__.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels
creating build\lib\pretrainedmodels\datasets
copying pretrainedmodels\datasets\utils.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\datasets
copying pretrainedmodels\datasets\voc.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\datasets
copying pretrainedmodels\datasets\__init__.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\datasets
creating build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\bninception.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\cafferesnet.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\dpn.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\fbresnet.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\inceptionresnetv2.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\inceptionv4.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\nasnet.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\nasnet_mobile.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\pnasnet.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\polynet.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\resnext.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\senet.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\torchvision_models.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\utils.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\vggm.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\wideresnet.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\xception.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
copying pretrainedmodels\models\__init__.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models
creating build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features
copying pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features\resnext101_32x4d_features.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features
copying pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features\resnext101_64x4d_features.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features
copying pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features\__init__.py -> build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features
creating build\bdist.win-amd64
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\datasets
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\datasets\utils.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\datasets
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\datasets\voc.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\datasets
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\datasets\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\datasets
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\bninception.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\cafferesnet.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\dpn.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\fbresnet.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\inceptionresnetv2.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\inceptionv4.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\nasnet.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\nasnet_mobile.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\pnasnet.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\polynet.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features\resnext101_32x4d_features.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features\resnext101_64x4d_features.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\senet.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\torchvision_models.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\utils.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\vggm.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\wideresnet.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\xception.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\models\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\utils.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\version.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels
copying build\lib\pretrainedmodels\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\datasets\utils.py to utils.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\datasets\voc.py to voc.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\datasets\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\bninception.py to bninception.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\cafferesnet.py to cafferesnet.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\dpn.py to dpn.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\fbresnet.py to fbresnet.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\inceptionresnetv2.py to inceptionresnetv2.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\inceptionv4.py to inceptionv4.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\nasnet.py to nasnet.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\nasnet_mobile.py to nasnet_mobile.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\pnasnet.py to pnasnet.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\polynet.py to polynet.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext.py to resnext.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features\resnext101_32x4d_features.py to resnext101_32x4d_features.cpython-37.pyc
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build\\bdist.win-amd64\\egg\\pretrainedmodels\\models\\resnext_features\\__pycache__\\resnext101_32x4d_features.cpython-37.pyc.1702181039952'
```

Comment: can you pust the full traceback error ?

Comment: @MiguelTrejo Please see the edit

Comment: have you tried on a conda env?

Comment: I have anaconda installed...what command should I try?

Comment: [create](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) a new conda env, and after activating it just clone the repo and install the  `setup.py` , it has as requirements torch, torchvision, etc, so it will install them. That's what worked for me

Comment: Thanks Miguel, but I get the same error. The steps I did were:
conda create --name myenv
Proceed? y
conda activate myenv
git clone (the repo)
cd pretrained-models.pytorch
python setup.py install

And I still get the same error.

Comment: A third option can be with a conda env inside a docker container

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a docker image, one I frequently use is the `datascience-notebook` image from jupyter.

For this:

- 1. Install docker desktop for Windows, refer to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/).
- 2. Enable file sharing inside Docker Destop Settings[image]

As you can see from the `C:users\amtre` I can mount any subdirectory to the container, for example, all that is within the `Documents` folder.

- 3. Once docker has access to mount directories to a container we will be using the jupyter [datascience-notebook](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/) as it already comes with some packages as default. Type on your terminal

```
docker run -it -e GRANT_SUDO=yes --user root --rm -p 8888:8888 -p 4040:4040 -v C:/users/amtre/Documents:/home/jovyan/work jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

it will take a while pulling the docker image, but at the end you will get the URL to access the notebook as the image above shows.
[image]

4. Inside Jupyter, open a terminal and type

```
git clone https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch.git
cd pretrained-models.pytorch
python setup.py install
```

this will also install `'torch', 'torchvision', 'munch', 'tqdm'` as it comes in `install_requires` on the `setup.py`. When the installation is done, you should be able to start using pretrained models

[image]

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I'll give it a try. Any idea why this error occurred, though? It seems like something is missing from the installation, and I'm not sure why this would be solved by installing within a virtualenv or jupyter notebook.

Comment: The build stage creates `creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pretrainedmodels\models\resnext_features`, but I'm not sure about why would a file under `__pycache__` is accessed during the byte compiling step.